# Import post data to vBulletin5

Tags: php, vbulletin

I want to import some contents into vBulletin Forums System. I am using vBulletin 5. I don't have experience working with vBulettin, I want to export posts and contents to something like csv and import them to VB Forum someway.

Any help or suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific programming questions; please see [how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A general question like this is too broad; you would be better off googling for a tutorial on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The exact process depends on what type of forum you are importing from. Importing to vBulletin from phpBB might differ from IPB or Xenforo.

I would start by looking at [vBulletin's import documentation](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/impex_import) using ImpEx.